# How to open Gmail, Google Calendar, Google Docs in the same tab

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, google-docs

I don't want to open those applications in separate tabs because it is annoying.

Anyone, knows any solution?

Comment: Do you have a 2800x1200 screen or what? :p

Comment: we need more information on what your question is. do you wan't a separate window for each?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When you're at one Google site and you use the navigation bar at the top of the page to click another Google site, it opens in a new window or tab instead of opening in-place, the way ordinary links do. Coola evidently doesn't want to open a new tab. (I'm the same way; when I click a link, it's because I'm finished with the current page, so I have no need for the existing page to remain.)

Comment: That's right Mr. Kennedy :)

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a clunky solution, but you can drag the link for the "other" app into your address bar, and your browser will open it in the same window. For example, if you're in Gmail and want to go to Calendar, just drag the Calendar link and drop it in the address bar.